# How to add iris w arducopter to existing world

Tags: gazebo

Start with roslaunch vrx_gazebo vrx.launch

I would like to add an iris quadcopter with arducopter between the tent and the posts

I added the following lines to the file example_course.world.xacro, after Wind.

```
<include> <uri>model://iris_with_ardupilot</uri>
<pose>-534 150 1 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
```

But I don't see the quadcopter and rostopic list doesn't show additional topics.